# How can I run the original Diablo 1 on OS X Lion (10.7)?

Tags: macos, diablo

Hankering for some *Diablo 1*, but most resources online only cover *Diablo 2*. Is there easy way to run it natively? Would old Mac emulation work in lieu of dual-booting Windows? Is *Diablo 1* feeble enough to run well in virtualization? Should I virtualize Snow Leopard with Rosetta instead of Windows? What route has the highest chances of success?

Comment: The reason this doesn't work in OS X is that OS 9 apps (the original Diablo is one of these) aren't compatible with OS X. You will need more than Rosetta (which [simply put] translates PPC calls to x86) in order to run the original Diablo on a Mac. You will also need something to convert M68K calls to Intel in order to get the game to work correctly. Sheepsaver will get the job done, but you will have performance, audio (issues with the music), and video issues (restricted resolution, etc), as it was never meant to emulate games.

Answer (score 4):

You can't run it through a normal method.

Here is what I found:

> To recap:
>
> - Classic won't work since you're running an Intel. Diablo under Classic (on PPC) works poorly or not at all anyway, in my experience.
> - You can try [SheepShaver](http://www.freemacware.com/sheepsaver/). However: it can be confusing to set up (the linked directions @Xeem are pretty good); you need an OS 8 or 9 system
>     folder/disc to run it (NOT downloadable from Apple); and it's pretty
>     unstable for gaming in any case - this on my PPC, which runs it
>     natively.
> - The Windows solution. Since the Battle Chest CDs are hybrids, you'll have a PC version to run. However, you'll have to buy a copy of
>     Parallels/VMWare. Why not just do Boot Camp for free? Even then, you'd
>     still need (have to buy?) a copy of Windows XP. A little pricey to run
>     one old game.
>
> Short answer: there's no one solution that's both easy and free,
>   sadly.
>
> I can understand why you'd want to play Diablo, though. #II has more
>   choices, but seems to devolve into a constant flood of A. weak items
>   for your class or B. great items for another class, requiring you to
>   town-portal every 5 minutes to free up space. Diablo really had the
>   formula down of streamlined dungeon crawling, nearly every item an
>   improvement, and click-click-click gaming.

*In this topic, they advise the person to try Diablo 2 instead, because it'll provide more choices to run.*

Source[¹](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=3819060&postcount=9) [²](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=319303)

Those are other two links that say more or less the same.

- [Diablo 1 on OSX 10.5?](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=325876)
- [Any way to play old Diablo 1 on OSX?](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=60933)

Comment: Lion doesn't support running Windows XP through Boot Camp, unfortunately.

Comment: @Adeese I didn't knew that, I use win7 with my Lion. =X Thanks for the information =)

Comment: If you can get a PPC Mac that has Tiger (10.4) and below, you can boot it up in Classic mode and install/play the game.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to play Diablo through your web browser : https://d07riv.github.io/diabloweb/ .

Details about the project - https://github.com/d07RiV/diabloweb .

It allows you to provide path to original Diablo files on your disk so you can play game legally.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with either VMWare (preferred) or VirtualBox. The game is very old and should have no problem running in a virtual machine. You should use Windows XP.

I think even Diablo 2 will run fine in a VM, but this always depends on the host system etc. A guideline is to use a system that is 10X faster than the requirement.

Sometimes graphic cards have problems with VMs, but both games do not need any graphics acceleration.

My personal experience is that you should invest some money in a good virtualization solution as the freeware tools do not support graphics acceleration. Still Diablo 1 should run fine in either.

I do not own a Mac, but a friend recently installed Age of Empires 2 in VMWare Fusion and we could play.

Comment: Hey there Mr. Downvotey McDownvoter, would you mind leaving a comment as to why you downvoted?

Comment: I think this person thought the 'natively' part is mandatory. I interpreted it as a suggested option, which my solution does address.